# Railsで複数条件のLEFT JOINをかくには

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, sql, rails-activerecord

```
ModelA
  - id
  - c_id
  - d_id

ModelB
  - id
  - name
  - c_id
  - d_id
```

`ModelA` と `ModelB` の共有のカラムは `c_id` と `d_id` です。

```
SELECT 
  A.id, B.name
FROM
  ModelA AS A
  LEFT JOIN ModelB AS B
    ON A.c_id = B.c_id AND A.d_id = B.d_id
```

Rails(ActiveRecord)でこのようなデータ取得はどうしたらいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`joins` を使って以下のように書きます。

```
ModelA.joins(%{
  LEFT JOIN model_bs
  ON model_a.c_id = model_b.c_id AND model_a.d_id = model_b.d_id
}).select("*, model_b.name AS b_name").map { |a| a.b_name }
```

ここで `model_a`, `model_b` はテーブル名です。得られるレコードは ModelA のインスタンスですが、`name` は特異メソッド `name` を経由して得ることが出来ます。

ON句で複合キーを指定した場合、SQL (の一部) を直接書く以外に方法は無いです。多分。